# Matrix of WS2812b powered in 24v (LEDs 5 by 5)

Tags: power, power-consumption, ws2812b

In order to reduce the power for a large quantity of WS2812b matrix, I would like to power it directly by 24V, by intuition, chaining in series 5 LEDs (for the power only, the data will be one by one to be able to address each LED).

As it's just an intuition, but I'm not really expert on it, can you please tell me what do you think about this solution?

Can you please help me to confirm the power consumption for a matrix of 100 LEDs, grouped by pack of 5 LEDs.

Will this improve consumption as compared to powering all 100 LEDs in parallel from a 5V power supply?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can do this with addressable LEDs. They use constant current drivers to drive the LEDs. I would expect very erratic behaviour

Comment: Question, do I need to add a resistor per branch to fix the intensity ?

Comment: Thanks Makoto, I didn't thought about that. I will try to check for that.

Comment: You can't reduce the power. The requirement will be the same whether they're in series or parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good way to smoke a load of LEDs!

They draw current depending on the individual unit brightness settings, so this will not work (Among other reasons having to do with the need to level translate the data between each stage).

Use a small switching regulator to take the 24V down to 5V and use that to power them in the normal way.

Regards, Dan.

Comment: It was worth a try ... ;-)
Thanks a lot.